# What are the Class Badges for?

Tags: dawn-of-heroes

Among other loot, I'm occasionally awarded with Badges. There seems to be many different badges, each corresponding to a particular character class. They all sport the same item description;

> Gives the user a higher Rank and changes his or her appearance to a *Veteran*.

I put *Veteran* in italics because in the game's item description, the word is colored yellow, showing it's of some importance.

What does **higher Rank** mean? What does **Veteran** mean?
What do these items do? They clearly make my characters appear different, but do they have any other significance?

Comment: @Kotekzot what do you mean?

Comment: @kotekzot are you saying the badges do nothing and your sure of this fact? or merely referencing the fact that I'm not sure what they do so they must be hats?